# BST with OOP Principles in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm confused about BST. Im trying to learn how can i make BST on C++ so here is my code. I was sure I write truly but I dont know why its not working. Ive createn a class that BinarySearchTree , and structure as a private in this class. I tried to run and build that code before testing in main. That didnt show any exception but when I call the function insert in main. Then run and build. It says windows cancelled the programming thats running error. I really couldnt understand whats wrong. If someone can explain clearly where was im wrong. I'm really appreciate that. Thanks for your helping..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    struct TreeNode
    {
        int key; 
        TreeNode* left;
        TreeNode* right; 
    };
    TreeNode* root; //root pointer

public:
    void insert(int value)
    {
         TreeNode* leaf_node; 
         TreeNode* t,*curr_node; 
         t->key = value; 
         t->right = NULL;
         t->left = NULL;

         if(root == NULL)
         {
             root  = t; //t is root now
         }
         else
         {

             curr_node = root;

             while(curr_node != NULL)
             {

                    leaf_node = curr_node;
                    if(value > curr_node ->key)
                    {
                        curr_node = curr_node->right;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curr_node = curr_node->left;
                    }
             }
            if(value > leaf_node ->key)
            {
                leaf_node->right = t;
            }
            else
            {
                leaf_node->left = t;
            }

         }
    }
    void remove(int value)
    {

        TreeNode* curr_node,*parent;
        if (root == NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Tree is empty..!"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        //We keep a variable called found
        int found = false;
        curr_node = root;
        while(curr_node != NULL)
        {
            if(curr_node->key == value)
            {
                found = true;
               break;
            }

            parent = curr_node;
            if(value > curr_node->key)
            {
                curr_node = curr_node->right;
            }
            else
            {
                curr_node = curr_node ->left;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
            cout<<"Value Not Found ..!"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        if(curr_node->right == NULL && curr_node->left == NULL)
        {
            if(parent->right == curr_node)
            {
                parent->right = NULL;
                delete curr_node;
            }
            else
            {
                parent->left = NULL;
                delete curr_node;
            }
            return;
        }

          if(curr_node->right!= NULL && curr_node->left == NULL)
        {
            if(parent->left == curr_node)
            {
                parent->left = curr_node->right;
                delete curr_node;
            }
            else
            {
                 parent->right= curr_node->right;
                delete curr_node;
            }
            return;
        }
        if(curr_node->right== NULL && curr_node->left != NULL)
        {
            if(parent->left == curr_node)
            {
                parent->left = curr_node->right;
                delete curr_node;
            }
            else
            {
                 parent->right= curr_node->right;
                delete curr_node;
            }
            return;
        }

        TreeNode* check_node = curr_node->right;
        if(check_node->left == NULL)
        {

            curr_node->key = check_node->key;
            curr_node->right = check_node->right;
            delete check_node;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode* successor,*parent;
            parent = check_node;
            successor = check_node->left;
            while(successor->left != NULL)
            {
                parent = successor;
                successor = successor->left;
            }
            curr_node->key =  successor->key;
            parent->left = successor->right;
            delete successor;
        }
    }
    void inorder()
    {
        //recursive
        inorder(root);
    }
    void inorder(TreeNode* temp)
    {
        if(temp == NULL) return;
        inorder(temp->left);
        cout<<temp->key<<" ";
         inorder(temp->right);
        cout<<temp->right<<" ";
    }
};
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    //Testing The Code
    BinarySearchTree t;
    t.insert(8);
    t.insert(3);
    t.insert(1);
    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(10);
    t.insert(9);
    t.insert(12);
    t.insert(11);
    //t.remove(22);
    //t.remove(11);
    //t.remove(12);
    //t.remove(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the error and where it was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
...
TreeNode* t, ...;
t->key = value;
...
```

You declare a pointer -- which points to some random point in memory -- and then write into that space. This is called **dereferencing an uninitialized pointer**, and it causes **undefined behavior**, which means there's no limit to how bad the effects can be.

You must construct such variables, like this:

```
TreeNode* t = new TreeNode;
t->key = value;
```

The deeper problem is that you wrote far too much code before testing any of it. You should have tried creating one node and assigning a value to it, before you attempted a tree of them; you would have made the same bug, but it would have been much easier to find.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answering, I did what you said but still not working.  I'm just beginner in C++ but I really would love to learn this language. If its possible could you look at that again little bit. Cause I have changed every TreeNode* t sth like that to TreeNode* t = new TreeNode :(

Comment: @Orkun: Did you try writing a simpler program, that creates a pointer to a node and assigns values to its fields, as I suggested? If that fails, edit your question to add the (minimal) code at the end, and we'll try to solve the problem.